# Add custom elements to React Table pagination-top

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm looking to conditionally add a button to my React Table, and for it to display to the right of the row size selector in the `PaginationTop` section.

The project is currently using react-table `6.9.2`.

Currently the table simply uses `showPaginationTop` as an argument in the `ReactTable` component, resulting in this header after some custom css:
[image: table header]

With a custom element displaying, I'm looking for it to appear as:
[image: new table header]

Does anyone know if this is possible without changing the react-table source for `PaginationTop`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, this can be done with component overriding as mentioned in the documentation here:
https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#component-overrides

For my solution this involved making a new component and setting it as the default:

```
Object.assign(ReactTableDefaults, {
  PaginationComponent: Pagination,
...
```